# Race condition using GCD in swift

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to simulate a race condition by allowing multiple threads to read and write a shared state. But somehow in the end the result is correct. Below is the code i am using to simulate the behavior.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "my-queue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: [.concurrent, .initiallyInactive])
var val = 0
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
queue.async {
    for _ in 0..<100 {
        val += 1
    }
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
queue.async {
    for _ in 0..<100 {
        val += 1
    }
    group.leave()
}

queue.activate()

group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    print("Done incrementing final value is \(val)")
}
```

> Output is : Done incrementing final value is 200

The question is how the final output is 200 when multiple threads are reading and writing a single value?

Comment: Have you run this code in a real app? Playgrounds are known to be behave incorrectly for complex memory and asynchronous cases.

Comment: Agreed about using a real app here, but I wouldn't call this "incorrectly." There is no promise by GCD that concurrent queues will be run in parallel, only that they are allowed to.

Comment: @PuneetSharma I checked and the behaviour is different in app vs playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not happen in a Playground.  Try running it in a real app.

The only way the two threads could interfere with each other is if one thread reads the value of `val` between the time the other thread reads the value and increments it.  You are likely just getting lucky as the time between reading `val` and writing it with the incremented value is really tiny.  Separate the reading and writing and introduce a delay (with `usleep`) and you will see the race condition:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "my-queue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: [.concurrent, .initiallyInactive])
var val = 0
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
queue.async {
    for _ in 0..<100 {
        let value = val
        usleep(10_000)
        val = value + 1
        print("val = \(val)")
    }
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
queue.async {
    for _ in 0..<100 {
        let value = val
        usleep(9_000)
        val = value + 1
        print("val = \(val)")
    }

    group.leave()
}

queue.activate()
```

Comment: Adding a delay is also producing the same output. No race condition. let me try running it in the real app instead of playground.

Comment: I tried it in an app and it showed the race condition.  Make the delays different so that the two threads get out of sync.

Comment: It works in the app, but not sure why its behaving differently in the playground. Thanks.